# python decode javascript btoa string

Tags: javascript, python

I am using this code in javascript to encode one json

```
a = {'address': "djdjdjdj", "provider": "google"}
{address: 'djdjdjdj', provider: 'google'}
btoa(a)
'W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd'
```

I am using this code to decode in backend

```
    import json
    import base64
    encodes_Str = "W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd"
    btoa = lambda x:base64.b64decode(x)
    atob = lambda x:base64.b64encode(bytes(x, 'utf-8')).decode('utf-8')
    decoded = json.loads(btoa(encodes_Str))
    print(decoded)
```

error:

```
    >>> decoded = json.loads(btoa("W29iamVjdCBPYmplY3Rd"))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 357, in loads
        return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
        raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
    >>>
```

I am getting above error. How can i get back the json which i encodes in javascript
please take a look

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you haven't converted your JavaScript object into a string before attempting to base64 encode it. Hence when you decode it in python, you get the string:

```
[object Object]
```

In your JavaScript you need to JSON encode the object first i.e.

```js
a = {'address': "djdjdjdj", "provider": "google"}
btoa(JSON.stringify(a))
```

This will give the string:

```
"eyJhZGRyZXNzIjoiZGpkamRqZGoiLCJwcm92aWRlciI6Imdvb2dsZSJ9"
```

which you can then run through

```py
json.loads(base64.b64decode(encodes_Str))
```

to get:

```
{'address': 'djdjdjdj', 'provider': 'google'}
```